# ansible playbook handling long running process

Tags: ansible-2.x

is it possible to handle processes that are long running and may not keep an application running in the cli.  for example   zfs scrub /tank  completes in a few seconds yet the process of the scrub continues in the background. there is a utility called zed that can run a script or other actions when the scrub completes to get the details of the scrub.  is there a way that ansible can handle situations like this to receive results and act on them or is this something that a tool like jenkins would be needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [wait_for](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html) module to make Ansible wait for the process to complete.

For example, you could configure the zed utility to create a file when the scrub process completes.

```
- name: Wait until the file /tmp/scrub-results is present before continuing
  wait_for:
    path: /tmp/scrub-results
```

The [wait_for](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html) module can test many other conditions such as the presence of an open port or specific content to appear in a file. It can also watch a specific process ID until it terminates.

It is best to read the documentation to determine which is most suitable for your use case.